# Footer Shading Height is wrong

Tags: html, css

I have a simple shading feature that goes across the bottom of the webpage regardless of size/dimensions (i hope).  However, the shading box won't expand beyond the height of the words.  I tried adding height variables and nothing works.  Help?

```
footer {
   position:fixed;
   height:20px;
   width:100%;
   bottom:0;
   z-index:1;
   }
footer small {
   width:100%;
   height:20px;
   float:left;
   right:5px;
   opacity: 0.6;
   background-color: #000000;
   clear:both;
   margin:0 0 0 0;
   color:#fff;
   text-align:right;
   }

footer a {
   color:#fff
}
```

I'm not even really sure how to phrase the questions so its difficult to find answers.  So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you could visually demonstrate using a fiddle, it'll help tremendously -- http://www.jsfiddle.net.

Comment: oh wow, never used fiddle before, here it goes:  http://jsfiddle.net/c9gkM/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle :).  So you've stated the problem, however it's not exactly clear what solution you're looking for.  Could you be a little more specific to what you're trying to accomplish?  Like maybe "make the shading twice the height of the words"?

Comment: Actually I would like to know how to manipulate it in general.  I tried height and a few other variables and I simply cannot get it to be bigger at all.  Once I know that I can mess around until I find the right size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cleaned up your code to make it a little easier to understand (and easier for me to explain)

```
// Control the shading
footer {
   // sets position of element relative to window
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   left: 0;

   display:block;
   background-color: #000000;
   opacity: 0.6;
   width:100%;
   height:20px;
   text-align:right;
   z-index:1;
}

// Control the text
footer small {
   color:#fff;
}

footer a {
   color:#fff
}
```

**Here's the fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/c9gkM/2/

A few things to know:

- `.footer` is used to manipulate the bottom div's properties *(i.e. height, background-color, etc)*.  This should allow you to edit the shading itself easily.
- `.footer small` is used to manipulate the text.  You can declare properties like *font-size, font-weight, color* to it.  Another trick is using `line-height` and declaring its value to vertically center the text inside the div (assuming it remains one line).

That's just a start; hopefully this should be a little easier to manage.